# Problems trying to install mingw python version

Tags: python, tensorflow, gtk, msys2

Greeting, I installed the mingw in MSYS2, but the python installed was the 3.8 version and I want to use TensorFlow with the GTK, but TensorFlow 2.0 is supported only with versions 3.6 and 3.7.
So, how should I install the python with a specific version? Spent a hour looking for the solving, but didn't find anything useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to mysys2 repo site, http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/
2. Download a copy of older version, for example, http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/python-3.6.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
3. Install the package with `pacman -U python-3.6.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`

I am not sure if you need to uninstall python3.8 first before running commands above.

Comment: The install was completed corretly, but no file was created in C:\msys64\mingw64\bin, the python was installed in C:\msys64\usr\bin. When I use the python in this folder and try to run my code it didn't work. It doesn't import "gi" nor "gtk.